# Extending Qt desktop application to web service with shared logic (MVC)

Tags: c++, qt, wt

So I have this task before me which requires a desktop client that can connect to a current C++ library. The plan is to develop this GUI in Qt. However, a webpage will be developed in a later stage as well. The webpage will not be as extensive as the Desktop version.

My question is therefore; would it be possible to develop a Qt GUI with separation of the logic (like mvc), and later on develop a web service using the same logic part? (using for example http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/)

Is there a better way? (as you might have guessed, we're aiming for platform independence. In our library this is achieved with the help of ACE)

Comment: AFAIK C++ executable can run only on platforms on which it is compiled. So you will have to generate different client application files for different platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac)

Comment: Yeah, recompiling is not a problem. Would prefer to "recode" as little as possible though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have made a decision to put all logic (for communication and scripting etc.) in the library. I can then connect a CLI, GUI or web service to the library and re-use most of my code in all sorts of clients.

The separation will therefore not be dependent on Qt separation, and the client can use any suitable language and design.